# Count number of key/value pairs in child of Redux reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Lets say my Redux reducer looks like this:

Users
       User1: James
       User2: Victoria
       User3: Colin
       User4: Lloyd

I would `passStateToProps` and then reference the Users object using `this.props.Users`.....however is there an easy function you can use to count the number of key/value pairs in there? (i.e. 4 in this case).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count object keys, there is Object.keys() method which takes Object as parameter and returns array of object keys.

In your case you can use below code, to get length.

```js
Object.keys(this.props.Users).length
```